# How to switch between operating systems

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, kodi, noobs

I am new to Raspberry Pi, and have just downloaded PINN, which I've read is an enhanced version of NOOBS. I was hoping that I could switch between LibreELEC and Raspbian whenever I booted up the Pi, but as soon as I turn it on, it automatically boots to Raspbian within a few seconds. I want to be able to switch between the 2 often, whilst also keeping the data. Any ideas on how to do this. Btw, I downloaded both of them at the start, but I'm stuck on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PINN like NOOBS is not really a boot manager, it allows multiple OS but boots to the default within a few seconds.

You can get to the screen that switches OS by pressing Shift during this brief period.

NOTE you MUST install all OS at the same time.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've noticed it works. If you download another OS afterwards through recovery mode, will it lose all of the data from the SD card?

Comment: PINN has changed since I last used it. In general changing OS loses the existing. I believe may possible to add a new OS if you shrink the existing, but you will have to study https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md It is, of course, possible to backup your data and restore and also to copy to a fresh PINN install on another SD Card - none of this is straightforward.